# unsolicited change of font size in mathjax in reveal.js slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, mathjax, reveal.js

Although the code for the slides (here `sections`) is exactly the same, I experience a change in the font size from the 3rd to the 4th slide. I have tried to track this down but I didn't find a cause.

Funnily, if I remove the `title` slide, this change occurs again between the 3rd and 4th slide.

Any ideas?

Here are two screenshots

[image: normal sized math display]
[image: smaller sized math display]

And here is the html code (that should work as a stand alone)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="pandoc">
  <meta name="author" content="Jan Heiland">
  <title>H_\infty-control for DAEs</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://revealjs.com/css/reveal.css">
  <style type="text/css">code{white-space: pre;}</style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://revealjs.com/css/theme/black.css" id="theme">
  <script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML-full" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="reveal">
   <div class="slides">

    <!-- section>
  <h1 class="title">Riccati-based <span class="math inline">\(H_\infty\)</span>-control for DAEs</h1>
  <p class="author">Jan Heiland</p>
  </section-->

  <section>
   <ul>
    <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
     <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
      \begin{bmatrix}
      C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
      \end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix}
      sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
      \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
      \end{align*}\]</span></li>
   </ul>
  </section>

  <section>
   <ul>
    <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
     <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
      \begin{bmatrix}
      C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
      \end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix}
      sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
      \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
      \end{align*}\]</span></li>
   </ul>
  </section>

  <section>
   <ul>
    <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
     <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
      \begin{bmatrix}
      C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
      \end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix}
      sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
      \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
      \end{align*}\]</span></li>
   </ul>
  </section>

  <section>
   <ul>
    <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
     <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
      \begin{bmatrix}
      C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
      \end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix}
      sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
      \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
      \end{align*}\]</span></li>
   </ul>
  </section>

   </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://revealjs.com/lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://revealjs.com/js/reveal.js"></script>

  <script>

// Full list of configuration options available at:
// https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
Reveal.initialize({

 // Optional reveal.js plugins
 dependencies: [
 { src: 'https://revealjs.com/lib/js/classList.js', condition: function() { return !document.body.classList; } },
 { src: 'https://revealjs.com/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true },
 { src: 'https://revealjs.com/plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true }
]
});
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `viewDistance` parameter to the number of slides you have will solve your problem.
Default value is 3, which automatically hide all the following (or the previous ones beyond this limit), setting them to `display:none;` and this doesn't allocate the space the slide should take

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="generator" content="pandoc">
        <meta name="author" content="Jan Heiland">
        <title>H_\infty-control for DAEs</title>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://revealjs.com/css/reveal.css">
        <style type="text/css">code{white-space: pre;}</style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://revealjs.com/css/theme/black.css" id="theme">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML-full" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">

                <section>
        <h1 class="title">Riccati-based <span class="math inline">\(H_\infty\)</span>-control for DAEs</h1>
        <p class="author">Jan Heiland</p>
        </section>

        <section>
            <ul>
                <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
                    <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
                        \end{bmatrix}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
                        \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
                        \end{align*}\]</span></li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <section>
            <ul>
                <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
                    <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
                        \end{bmatrix}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
                        \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
                        \end{align*}\]</span></li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <section>
            <ul>
                <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
                    <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
                        \end{bmatrix}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
                        \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
                        \end{align*}\]</span></li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <section>
            <ul>
                <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
                    <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
                        \end{bmatrix}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
                        \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
                        \end{align*}\]</span></li>
            </ul>
        </section>

            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://revealjs.com/lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://revealjs.com/js/reveal.js"></script>

        <script>

// Full list of configuration options available at:
// https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
Reveal.initialize({
    viewDistance: 5,
    // Optional reveal.js plugins
    dependencies: [
    { src: 'https://revealjs.com/lib/js/classList.js', condition: function() { return !document.body.classList; } },
    { src: 'https://revealjs.com/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true },
    { src: 'https://revealjs.com/plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true }
]
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT :**

Another simplest solution is to choose SVG output (no more worries with number of slides)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://revealjs.com/css/reveal.css">
        <style type="text/css">code{white-space: pre;}</style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://revealjs.com/css/theme/black.css" id="theme">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_SVG-full" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">

                <section>
        <h1 class="title">Riccati-based <span class="math inline">\(H_\infty\)</span>-control for DAEs</h1>
        <p class="author">Jan Heiland</p>
        </section>

        <section>
            <ul>
                <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
                    <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
                        \end{bmatrix}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
                        \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
                        \end{align*}\]</span></li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <section>
            <ul>
                <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
                    <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
                        \end{bmatrix}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
                        \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
                        \end{align*}\]</span></li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <section>
            <ul>
                <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
                    <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
                        \end{bmatrix}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
                        \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
                        \end{align*}\]</span></li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <section>
            <ul>
                <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
                    <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
                        \end{bmatrix}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
                        \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
                        \end{align*}\]</span></li>
            </ul>
        </section>

            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://revealjs.com/lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://revealjs.com/js/reveal.js"></script>

        <script>

// Full list of configuration options available at:
// https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
Reveal.initialize({
    viewDistance: 1,
    // Optional reveal.js plugins
    dependencies: [
    { src: 'https://revealjs.com/lib/js/classList.js', condition: function() { return !document.body.classList; } },
    { src: 'https://revealjs.com/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true },
    { src: 'https://revealjs.com/plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true }
]
});
        </script>
```

Comment: This works (almost) perfect for me. Also because I can invoke this parameter setting in my `pandoc` script with `-V viewDistance=15`. However, this *number of slides* bothers me a bit.

Comment: @Jan see my edit. Have you read this post on github ? https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/1924

Comment: Thanks for the link to the related github issue -- haven't read it before. And invoking SVG is a good workaround.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, from the 4th and up render of mathjax, it will render at `font-size 50%`
I don't know why, maybe some config you've overlooked. Anyway, you can override this by adding your own css:

```
.MathJax_CHTML {
    font-size: 117% !important;
}
```

117% was the value used for the other elements, so I would just use that value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="pandoc">
  <meta name="author" content="Jan Heiland">
  <title>H_\infty-control for DAEs</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://revealjs.com/css/reveal.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    code {
      white-space: pre;
    }
    
    .MathJax_CHTML {
      font-size: 117% !important;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://revealjs.com/css/theme/black.css" id="theme">
  <script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML-full" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="reveal">
    <div class="slides">

      <section>
        <h1 class="title">Riccati-based <span class="math inline">\(H_\infty\)</span>-control for DAEs</h1>
        <p class="author">Lars on stackoverflow</p>
        </section>

      <section>
        <ul>
          <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
            <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
                        \end{bmatrix}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
                        \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
                        \end{align*}\]</span></li>
        </ul>
      </section>

      <section>
        <ul>
          <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
            <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
                        \end{bmatrix}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
                        \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
                        \end{align*}\]</span></li>
        </ul>
      </section>

      <section>
        <ul>
          <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
            <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
                        \end{bmatrix}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
                        \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
                        \end{align*}\]</span></li>
        </ul>
      </section>

      <section>
        <ul>
          <li>Descriptor systems have an ODE part and an algebraic part
            <span class="math display">\[\begin{align*}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        C^{\mathsf{d}}  &amp; C^{\mathsf{a}}
                        \end{bmatrix}
                        \begin{bmatrix}
                        sI-A &amp; 0 \\ 0 &amp; sN-I
                        \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
                        \end{align*}\]</span></li>
        </ul>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://revealjs.com/lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://revealjs.com/js/reveal.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Full list of configuration options available at:
    // https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
    Reveal.initialize({

      // Optional reveal.js plugins
      dependencies: [{
          src: 'https://revealjs.com/lib/js/classList.js',
          condition: function() {
            return !document.body.classList;
          }
        },
        {
          src: 'https://revealjs.com/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js',
          async: true
        },
        {
          src: 'https://revealjs.com/plugin/notes/notes.js',
          async: true
        }
      ]
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This solution seems a bit hacky. But, surely, it works.